# Invalid result in coordinate transformation

Tags: coordinate-system, gdal, proj4js

I want to convert local coordinate (SWEREF99) to  Global coordinate(WGS 84). I tried 3 different ways and all produce almost same result which is not correct.
From here I got actual result: https://www.lantmateriet.se/sv/Sjalvservice/enkel-koordinattransformation/

**Input:** 6589150 1677500

**Expected output:** 59.21888889 18.92916667

**EGSG codes:**

EPSG:3011 : SWEREF99 18 00

EPSG 4326 : WGS 84

But what I got form different options:

**1. https://epsg.io/**

Output: 68.45944444 9.87361111

**2. proj4js**

Output: 68.45962374786117, 9.873651976751825

```
      var firstProjection = '+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=18 +k=1 +x_0=150000 +y_0=0 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs';
      var secondProjection = '+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs';
      var output = proj4(firstProjection, secondProjection, [6589150, 1677500]);
```

**2. GDAL**

Output: 68.8978437634193 9.65669736119052

```
      gdaltransform -s_srs EPSG:3011 -t_srs EPSG:4326
      6589150 1677500
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it cannot be answered as it stands now. The reference tool does not give the same result that is given in the question with the given coordinates, and alternative East coordinate value given in a comment leads to an error.

Answer (score 1):

1)
If [this](https://www.lantmateriet.se/sv/Sjalvservice/enkel-koordinattransformation/) was your reference tool, then the correct EPSG would be EPSG:3006, i.e., **SWEREF 99 TM**. This is (further) confirmed using the official [Control Points](https://www.lantmateriet.se/contentassets/a7ddfc3b7821498da8b55cd3f71b5150/kontrollpunkter_sweref99tm.pdf)

2)
It also appears that your "flat Easting coordinate" value i.e., *1677500* looks off. Perhaps the correct value was *677500*?

3)
Using 6589150N and 677500E, the results are as below.

[image]

[image]

---

Reply to comment from Questioner

> *Question perspective your are right, but I actual problem is values of X and Y. >It should be interchanged and value 1677500->167750*

The [SWEREF 99 web tool](https://www.lantmateriet.se/sv/Sjalvservice/enkel-koordinattransformation/) uses X for (N)orthing or Latitude, and Y for (E)asting or longitude. This is a rather unfortunate choice, although not technically incorrect, because most software, including proj4.js, use X for longitude and Y for latitude.

If your Easting is 167750, then it won't compute. You can try it yourself in the [SWEREF 99 web tool](https://www.lantmateriet.se/sv/Sjalvservice/enkel-koordinattransformation/). And 1677500 appears "out of bound".

Comment: Question perspective your are right, but I actual problem is values of X and Y. It should be interchanged  and value 1677500->167750